# How to create custom button or dropzone for Uploadthing in React?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've recently been using uploadthing for my storage and i really love it. but i'm only limited to the styling they provide for the `UploadButton` and `UploadDropzone` component. in their docs there is not much example to relate to as it is new. but i found this example to create a custom uploader function. [docs](https://docs.uploadthing.com/api-reference/react)

```
  const { startUpload } = useUploadThing("myUploadEndpoint", {
    onClientUploadComplete: () => {
      alert("uploaded successfully!");
    },
    onUploadError: () => {
      alert("error occurred while uploading");
    },
  });
```

in the above code it doesn't show how `useUploadThing` import came to be. i've checked their github repo but it doesn't have the imported file. can anyone show me how to customize the components or create a new component and upload using uploadthing?

Answer (score 0):

When I create Custom components with uploadthing. I import {useUploadthing} from  "../lib/utils/uploadthing";

And what is in the lib file is `export const { useUploadThing, uploadFiles } = generateReactHelpers<OurFileRouter>()`;

generateReactHelpers is gotten from `import { generateReactHelpers } from "@uploadthing/react/hooks";`

Answer (score 0):

[link to docs](https://docs.uploadthing.com/getting-started/solid#advanced-usage-useuploadthing/)

First, generate a typed hook using the generateSolidHelpers function from `@uploadthing/solid`:

`~src/utils/uploadthing.ts`

```
import { generateSolidHelpers } from "@uploadthing/solid";
 
import type { OurFileRouter } from "~/server/uploadthing";
 
export const { useUploadThing } = generateSolidHelpers<OurFileRouter>();
```

use the hook in your component. By using the hook, you have full control of when and how to upload files.

`~src/routes/index.tsx`

```
import { useUploadThing } from "~/utils/uploadthing";
 
async function compress(file: File) {
  // Run some compression algorithm on the file
  return file;
}
 
export default function Home() {
  const { startUpload } = useUploadThing("profileImage", {
    onClientUploadComplete: () => {
      alert("Upload Completed");
    },
  });
 
  return (
    <main>
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={async (e) => {
          const file = e.target.files?.[0];
          if (!file) return;
 
          // Do something with the file before uploading
          const compressed = await compress(file);
 
          // Then start the upload of the compressed file
          await startUpload([compressed]);
        }}
      />
    </main>
  );
}
```